# Difference between "like water" and "like there's no tomorrow"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'like water' and 'like there's no tomorrow'? I searched them in some dictionaries but I couldn't be sure about it.

Comment: Could you use it in a sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Like water" means in great quantities, lavishly, freely, abundantly.

"Like there's no tomorrow" means that it is done very fast, in great quantities, in a careless way, without thinking about the future.

They can be used pretty much interchangeably when talking for example about lavish spending. I feel that the second expression emphasizes the carelessness component (which is also present in the first one) by being more histrionic. Teenagers would typically use the second one because of its melodrama about the tomorrow.